# Doubts about type inference when using pick of zodObject

Tags: typescript, zod

when calling the pick method of a `zodObject` in a function by passing in a reference, how to set the type of `T` to ensure the correct type of return value？

```js
function zodPickDemo<T extends ZodObject<ZodRawShape>>(src: T) {
  return src.pick({ id: true });
}

const dto = z.object({ id: z.string(), name: z.string() });
const picked = zodPickDemo(dto);
// In this case the type of picked is not the expected type
```

In the above code, the type expected to be obtained is a zodObject object type containing only the id, but what is obtained is a type such that:

```js
z.ZodObject<Pick<z.ZodRawShape, never>, "strip", z.ZodTypeAny, {}, {}>
```

Playground: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-iauawv?file=src%2Fmain.ts&terminal=dev)

Comment: Well, what *is* the expected type and what did you get instead?

Comment: @hittingonme Thank you for your reply, I have updated the description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found this: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/567

For the time being, this is the way to handle it.

```js
ZodObject<
  Pick<ReturnType<T["_def"]["shape"]>, 'id'>,
  T["_def"]["unknownKeys"],
  T["_def"]["catchall"]
>
```